# FInding the row of selected control (shape)

Tags: excel, vba

Here Is a sample of the table with arrows:

[image]

When I press arrow I want to get corresponding target field value
And I want to assign one macro for all arrows.

I have done for first arrow

```
Sub Arrow()
dim targetField as String
    targetField = Sheet1.Cells(11, 4).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: [link](http://www.xlorate.com/excel-questions.html#Find%20Button%20Range) - Click the link to find how to find the range of a clicked button or shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found simple solution

```
Sub Arrow()
 Dim r As Range
    'find the range of the button clicked.
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell
     targetField = r.Offset(0, -1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I press second arrow I want to run this(Arrow()) macro and
>   increment row number

Do you really want to do that?
If so, the following pseudo code does that.

```
dim rVar as Int
dim cVar as Int

rVar = 11
cVar = 4

targetField = Sheet1.Cells(rVar, cVar).Value

rVar+1
cVar+1
```

But that is probably not what you are trying to do.
Instead of hardcoding row and column and then incrementing, consider finding the range of the object clicked and then use that as your navigation startpoint, for example: select column 0 (the one your arrow is in) and -2 row (two steps to the left from your arrows position)